# Bloquear salida en rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

En rmarkdown quiero bloquear los distintos mensajes que suelen salir.

Tengo puesto

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE)

```
````

Pero al hacer

```
 datos<- gdata::remove.vars(datos,c("Modelo","Version"))
```

Me imprime por pantalla, y también en el pdf al exportar

```
Changing in datos 
Dropping variables: Modelo, Version
```

¿Qué tengo que poner para que no me imprima estos avisos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mirando el código de la función `gdata::remove.vars` encuentras que la impresión de esas líneas se hace con `cat()`, una función primitiva para concatenar salidas en pantalla. Es decir, ese texto no sale en el contexto de un `message` o `warning`, por eso no se suprime con tus `opts$chunk`.

No conozco ninguna forma en que `knitr::knit` (que es la función que crea el documento pdf/html/etc. a partir de rmarkdown) pueda suprimir una salida de `cat()`. He buscado bastante en la documentación tratando de resolver un problema similar con otra librería y lo único que encontré es una solución indirecta.

En el chunk en el que está la llamada a la función problemática puedes anular toda salida en pantalla con `{r include = FALSE}`. Como eso también podría anular salidas que sí te interesan luego en otro `chunk` con `include = TRUE` (es así por defecto) puedes hacer un `print(objeto_que_salió_de_remove.vars)`.

Otra alternativa es no usar `gdata` y hacer las mismas operaciones con otras librerías que no tengan ese comportamiento. Esto no siempre es posible.

Una tercera alternativa es modificar a las funciones del paquete y eliminar las líneas que tiene esos `cat()`. Podrías que clonar la librería, modificarla y mantenerla.

Answer (score 1):

Una alternativa, siempre que estés dispuesto a modificar tú código, es usar [`capture.output()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.6.2/topics/capture.output) y asignar el resultado a una variable:

````
```{r echo=TRUE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
library("gdata")

data <- data.frame(x=1:10,y=1:10,z=1:10)
salida <- capture.output(data <- rename.vars(data, c("x","y","z"), c("first","second","third")))
data
```
````

---

También puedes revisar algunas de [estas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34208564/how-to-hide-or-disable-in-function-printed-message) posibilidades.